# Kafka Multi-tenancy

Tags: apache-kafka, distributed-computing, multi-tenant, confluent-platform

Is it possible to create multiple independent clusters on a distributed environment and manage it through the confluent control center? If yes, how can I do that on AWS cloud?

Comment: Note: Confluent Cloud is already a multi-tenant environment that can be used in AWS

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the exact product name. I am talking about Confluent Enterprise, not Confluent Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add multiple clusters to Control Center via the Clusters tab.

In fact, the production deployment pattern on the Confluent site actual recommends using a dedicated "metrics Kafka cluster" that sits alongside your other producer/consumer cluster(s), with all MetricsReporter configurations pointing at the other cluster. This way, if your "main cluster" is down, then Control Center would still be available

Comment: Does Confluent Enterprise support the multi-tenant feature?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Apache Kafka alone can support multi tenancy; by default a simple 3 node cluster can handles tens to hundreds of apps with hundreds of topics, producers and consumers. Confluent doesn't alter that code in their releases. There's no difference between Confluent OSS and Confluent Enterprise other than the addition of extra closed-source software and access to the Confluent Support system.